# Issue with recursion because thread suspension

Tags: java, recursion

I was playing around with a few practice problems in Java. I wrote a recursive program for program given below. My solution is right except for the suspended (which I believe) gets back to active state and changes the value of the recursive method. I have also added a screenshot of Eclipse in debug mode where the thread stack is shown.

```
package com.nix.tryout.tests;
/**
 * For given two numbers A and B such that 2 <= A <= B,
 * Find most number of sqrt operations for a given number such that square root of result is a whole number and it is again square rooted until either the 
 * number is less than two or has decimals. 
 * example if A = 6000 and B = 7000, sqrt of 6061 = 81, sqrt of 81 = 9 and sqrt of 9 = 3. Hence, answer is 3
 * 
 * @author nitinramachandran
 *
 */
public class TestTwo {

    public int solution(int A, int B) {
        int count = 0;

        for(int i = B; i > A ; --i) {

            int tempCount = getSqrtCount(Double.valueOf(i), 0);

            if(tempCount > count) {
                count = tempCount; 
            }
        }

        return count;
    }

    // Recursively gets count of square roots where the number is whole
    private int getSqrtCount(Double value, int count) {

        final Double sqrt = Math.sqrt(value);

        if((sqrt > 2) && (sqrt % 1 == 0)) {
            ++count;
            getSqrtCount(sqrt, count);
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestTwo t2 = new TestTwo();

        System.out.println(t2.solution(6550, 6570));
    }
}
```

[image]

The above screenshot is from my debugger and I've circled the Thread stack. Can anyone try and run the program and let me know what the problem is and what would be the solution? I could come up with a non recursive solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursion is wrong, since the value of `count` will return in any case `0` or `1` even if it goes deep down into recursive calls. Java is pass by value, meaning that modifying the value of a primitive inside of a method wont be visible outside of that method. In order to correct this, we can write the following recursion:

```
private int getSqrtCount(Double value) {

    final Double sqrt = Math.sqrt(value);

    if((sqrt > 2) && (sqrt % 1 == 0)) {
        return getSqrtCount(sqrt) + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. The code suggested by @Sean F is the closest fix. I am just wondering which would be a better solution in terms of of complexity and performance.

Comment: In my opinion, haven an input as a counter variable a bad practice. Basically returning the same value as a result is even worse. Try running your code with other value than `0` for `count` parameter. The complexity of the solution is the same in any case, which is `nloglogk`, where `n` is the positive difference between `A` and `B` and `k` is the current value if `i`.

Comment: Thank you @Ervin Szilagyi. What you said makes sense.

Comment: omg, I did phrase so bad. Correction: "In my opinion, having an input as a counter variable is a bad practice..."

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong, you should have

```
return getSqrtCount(sqrt, count);
```

instead of

```
getSqrtCount(sqrt, count);
```

Otherwise the recursion is pointless, you're completely ignoring the result of the recursion.

Comment: Thanks mate. I don't know how I missed the return statement.!